# Expression.Lambda variable '' of type 'System.String' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to build a system that loads function delegates to a dictionary and then they can be called from anywhere in the environment asking the dictionary for the delegate.

My functions are of a format `Func<string, string>`.

My code is

```
var methods = typeof(Keywords)
    .GetMethods()
    .Where(mt => mt.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KDTAttribute), false).Count() > 0);

foreach (var method in methods)
{
    string key = ((KDTAttribute)method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KDTAttribute), false)[0]).Keyword;
    var combinedArgumentsExp = new Expression[] { Expression.Parameter(typeof(string),"param") };
    var mtCall = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(me), method,combinedArgumentsExp);
    ParameterExpression targetExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "param");
    Func<string, string> result = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, string>>(mtCall, targetExpr).Compile();
    retVal.Add(key, result);
}
```

I get the exception on the `Expression.Lambda` line :

> variable 'param' of type 'System.String' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined.

P.S:
If there is a better way to load delegates to a dictionary at run time I'll be happy for any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `Expression.Parameter` twice, which gives you different expressions. Don't do that - just call it once, and use that `ParameterExpression` both places you need it:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string),"param");
string key = ((KDTAttribute)method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KDTAttribute), false)[0]).Keyword;
var mtCall = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(me), method, parameter);
var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, string>>(mtCall, parameter).Compile();
```